# Knife bootstrap command fails to install node on Ubuntu

Tags: chef-infra

I am running following command and knife doesn't node or chef-client

```
knife bootstrap IPADDRESS  -x username -P password-N "target1" -
```

Bootstrapping Chef on IPADDRESS

and then it comes out to command prompt. I go to hosted server and Nodes tab still is empty.

Comment: What is the command output? would you mind using `knife bootstrap -V` to see detailed output?

Comment: Why do you have a dash at the very end?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
knife bootstrap TARGET_IP_ADDR  -x USERNAME  -P PASSWORD  -N target1  --sudo
```

It will work.